# ASP.Net - any way to get a SiteMapPath that can show siblings?

Tags: asp.net, sitemappath

Is there any way to get a SiteMap control (ie. one that uses the Sitemap XML file) to display links to the sibling pages?

e.g. if my heirarchy is

```
Home
    Page1 (child of the home page)
    Page2 (another child of home page)
...
```

I would like a breadcrumb that when the user is looking at page 1 shows something like

> Home > **Page1** / *Page2*

And allows them to click on Home to go to the Home page, or on Page 2 to go to Page 2.
SiteMapPath itself seems to only support the link to Home page, so I'm wondering if there is a way to hack it, or an alternative control that will allow me to do this without too much additional code.

Comment: What do you want it to show if you have three pages and page 2 is the current page?

Comment: @Alexander - sorry if my post wasnt clear - i've edited above. Basically I want links between page1 and page2.

Answer (score 0):

SiteMapPath will only show the current path, not additional pages. But you can intercept the `ItemCreated` and `ItemDataBound` events and manipulate the items created there, like adding additional items and links.

Another option is to use the Menu control and force it to display after your liking with CSS.